# Raspberry Pi LED confusion

Tags: raspbian, led

I have had some issues with my raspberry pi. I went online to find some videos to try to figure out what is going on. I then noticed that their raspberry pies Have the LEDs OK, PWR,FDX,LNK and 100 (in that order). My raspberry pi does not have those. Mine has ACT,PWR,FDX,LNK,100. Is it a different type of model? Whats going on?

Comment: what is your model?

Comment: @SteveIrwin model b

Comment: @SteveIrwin and I bought it from newark.com . It came in 5 days

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do system LEDs signify?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-do-system-leds-signify)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THe ACT and the OK leds are the same thing.The name was changed in the revision.

From the raspberry pi [website](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1929),

> LED Marking
>
> Two minor changes have been made to the silk screen:
>
> D9 (Yellow LED) graphic changed from the incorrect 10M to 100 D5
>
> (Green LED) **graphic changed from OK to ACT (Activity)**

So the ACT led signifies activity same as the older versions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [elinux Rpi hardware page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware) (search down for "5 Status LEDs"), the green D5 light is labelled "OK" on rev. 1 boards and "ACT" on rev. 2 (which is what you have).