# What do the LEDs on the B+ mean?

Tags: led

Not a duplicate of [this RPi.SE question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-do-system-leds-signify), as I'll explain in a moment. `GPIO.RPI_REVISION` returns `3`.

As far as I can tell, looking at my B+, there are no LEDs labeled: `OK`, `FDX`, `LNK` or `10M`. There are two embedded in the Ethernet port, and two on the opposite side of the board. The ones on the Ethernet are unlabeled, but I can guess what they mean. The other two are labeled `ACT` and `PWR`.

`PWR` only turns on once in a great while. My RPi is running just fine, and the `PWR`  diode is unlit (which others say should never happen). This is the one that confises me the most.

`AMP` seems to turn on under I/O heavy load. (Seems to be the equivalent of the old `OK` LED).

What do these lights signify?

Comment: My B+ only seems to have two LEDs, ACT (activity) and PWR (power).  ACT flashes with SD card activity (although other software modules can also drive the LED) and PWR is on while 5V power is available.  If your PWR isn't on perhaps you have a poor power supply.  Mine has no Ethernet LEDs.

Comment: There are another two build into the Ethernet, if you look closely in the corners.

Comment: So there are.  I guess the yellow/orange is 100M and green is activity.

Comment: Can you find your board on any official site that looks like that? Maybe its a counterfeit?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I believe the following is correct for the B+.

**Red PWR LED**

- on if power OK
- flashes (or goes out) if the power drops below about 4.63V

**Green ACT LED**

- steady on if no SD card during boot
- irregular flashes for SD card access

**Ethernet Socket Left LED (yellow)**

- on 100-Mbps connection
- off 10-Mbps connection

**Ethernet Socket Right LED (green)**

- on if link established
- flashes for port activity
- off if no link is established

---

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=577688#p577688

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=646072#p646072

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9514.pdf

Comment: Ah, thank you. I suspect my power cable has a larger than normal voltage drop.

Comment: I usually power my Pis via the expansion header or back-powered through the USB ports (back-powering via the USB ports is not an option for the B+).

Comment: What does ACT stand for?

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 ACT stands for activity.  It can be configured to show different types of activity but the default is to show SD card access.