# Pi 4 ethernet connector LEDs

Tags: ethernet, led

My Pi 4 Model B - 2GB RAM SBC has an RJ45 ethernet connector. The connector itself has two inbuilt LEDs, one yellow, one green.

On some devices such as network switches, the colours can indicate link speed etc. What do the colours signify on a Pi 4?

Comment: Possibly the same answer as https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24664/what-do-the-leds-on-the-b-mean

Comment: That other question is 5 years old and refers to another model Pi with a different specification ethernet port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the PI 4 the yellow LED, the LINK LED, lights when ethernet is connected. Green LED is ACT LED. The LEDs don't change color with different speed. I've tried 10M, 100M and 1000M. Always both LEDs are working the same way.

Comment: the yellow one is called LINK light

Answer (score 0):

I have searched, unsuccessfully, for any documentation on the Ethernet LEDs and asked on the Forum, but got no replies.

`dtparam -h eth_led0 eth_led1` produces the following, but it is unclear what most of these mean.

```
eth_led0                Set mode of LED0 - amber on Pi3B+ (default "1"),
                        green on Pi4 (default "0").
                        The legal values are:
                        Pi3B+
                        0=link/activity          1=link1000/activity
                        2=link100/activity       3=link10/activity
                        4=link100/1000/activity  5=link10/1000/activity
                        6=link10/100/activity    14=off    15=on
                        Pi4
                        0=Speed/Activity         1=Speed
                        2=Flash activity         3=FDX
                        4=Off                    5=On
                        6=Alt                    7=Speed/Flash
                        8=Link                   9=Activity
eth_led1                Set mode of LED1 - green on Pi3B+ (default "6"),
                        amber on Pi4 (default "8"). See eth_led0 for
                        legal values.
```

On a Gigabit router:-

```
The Pi3B+ amber LED blinks.
The Green LED is off.

The Pi4 amber LED is on.
The Green LED blinks.

The Pi3B amber LED  is on.
The Green LED blinks.
Speed: 100Mb/s
```

There appears to be no consistency.

Out of curiosity I ran the command on my PiB+ running Stretch

```
eth_led0                Set mode of LED0 (usually orange) (default
                        "1"). The legal values are:
                        0=link/activity          1=link1000/activity
                        2=link100/activity       3=link10/activity
                        4=link100/1000/activity  5=link10/1000/activity
                        6=link10/100/activity    14=off    15=on
eth_led1                Set mode of LED1 (usually green) (default
                        "6"). See eth_led0 for legal values.
```