# RPi Zero Install

Tags: pi-zero, boot-issues, retropie

I have formatted my card and written the latest version of Pi Zero from the RetroPie website. Brand new microSD card, card reader, and HDMI wires. The tv screen stays blank when I plug the Pi0 in. I tried reformatting a few times. Unplugging/plugging in.

I'm really new to all this and I wasn't sure how long to wait before anything displayed upon initial boot? Or if I missed a crucial step? I don't think so, but I guess I don't know what I'm looking at. Thank you for your help. I am sure I formatted properly, then used win32 to write to the SD card. Then place it into the Pi, connect USB, HDMI, and power. But nothing. I've waited as long as 10 minutes, but still blank screen. :(

Comment: There is a green LED labelled ACT in the corner near the camera connector on the opposite side from the GPIO breakout.  What does it do when you plug in?

Comment: Thank you. It lightly flickers (not definite flashes), but then stabilizes within a  few seconds. Even now, it's steady on. I'm using a power source recommended by everyone I've studied from in these boards. 2.0 or greater. I tried to connect to a smaller HDTV, but it reads: "Not Supported" in the corner. But the main tv is a bigger one and it's just blank.

Comment: All I did was write the RetroPie 0/1 card image to the SDcard... Is that sufficient? I followed the directions at the RetroPie "First Installation" video to a T. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [the ACT LED] lightly flickers (not definite flashes), but then stabilizes within a few seconds. Even now, it's steady on.

The flickering is good, this indicates activity on the SD card.  The norm on a Pi Zero is for it to flicker irregularly for < 1 min and then remain on.  However, before that point you should see stuff on the screen.

You should try setting [`hdmi_safe=1`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md#hdmi_safe) or `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in `config.txt` on the first partition -- unless you are using a linux machine, you will probably see only that one.  If you can't find any partitions on the card, remake it.

If the green led is off, this is what will happen with no SD card in (i.e., it is being rejected right away, usually this is misformatting).<sup>1</sup>  Possibly it was doing the normal thing at one point and then got corrupted when you pulled the power, so you may have to recreate the card and set that option in `config.txt`.

---

<sup>1.  Beware, as per scitronboy's comment below, that the ACT led on the Pi Zero behaves inversely to that on other models.</sup>

Comment: @ SteveJ ,  goldilocks, **THAT IS NOT TRUE ON RPI ZERO.** On the rpi zero and zero w, the power light and ACT led are the same, so the ACT signals are inverted(the led is normally on, and it flickers off when the sd card is being accessed.) That way, you know when your rpi is on _and_ when the sd card is being accessed, with the same led.

Comment: @scitronboy Thanks much! I had a nagging feeling about that but was too lazy to plug one in and check (and unfortunately searching 'pi zero act led' did not produce anything definitive, so I assumed I was misremembering).

Comment: Thank you so much, goldilocks and scitronboy!! I edited the config file and it worked beautifully! Whew! Man, what a save!! I am very happy tonight!

Comment: @goldilocks see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/60563/78211

Comment: @Fabian Yes, that like other references fails to mention the fact that on the Zero models the ACT led is *on* when the system is idle.  I did get around to checking that first hand yesterday.  I've left a comment there for Dmitry.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is working, the green led flickering means that the rpi zero is successfully booting... so the problem is probably in your display mode or cable. Try this:

1. insert the sd card into a computer
2. open the 'boot' partition on the sd card. this partition will have files like `overlays`, `kernel.img`, `bcm2708-rpi-0-w.dtb`... It will likely be the only partition you can access.
3. open the file `config.txt`.
4. find the line(near the top) that says:

   `#hdmi_safe=1`

   and uncomment it so it reads

   `hdmi_safe=1`

   this will set the HDMI mode to "failsafe" settings.
5. If you can not find that line, just add

   `hdmi_safe=1`

   to the bottom of the file.
6. Also try un-commenting(removing the `#`) or adding a line that reads `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`. This will force HDMI output.
7. save the file, eject the sd card, and plug it back into the pi. turn the pi on and **make sure you have the right input mode slected on your tv.** You most likely have multiple HDMI plugs on your tv, so try scrolling through all the input options(by pressing he `input` button) on your tv(ie HDMI1, HDMI2, ANALOG, CABLE, etc.), until you find the one your pi is plugged into.

Hope this helps!!!

[see this to learn more about the config.txt file.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)

Comment: Thanks, scitronboy! You guys were a big help. If I may bend your ear once more, as you and godilocks have a ton more experience than me:

I am building a small retro arcade, using a Pi Zero, as a goodbye gift at work. So this entire project is being done on my TV. It works perfectly now. But I fear that when my friend gets it home, they'll plug it into whatever TV he has and this won't work. 

I tried plugging this pi into 2 other TVs in my own house and it's pretty sketchy. One just keeps rebooting, the other just did the initial boot and then went blank before ever getting to ES.

Comment: So if there is any thoughts about switching TVs or any ideas about recommenting those config files?? I don't know... thank you, though!

Comment: @SteveJ , the _monitor_ keeps rebooting or the _pi_ keeps rebooting? and on the second monitor, could you actually see the boot log scrolling by on the screen, or did the monitor just turn on? could you give us a few more details? _make sure your selecting the right input on your tv_

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the response. 

I'm on a 15" hdtv, brand is element. Some cheap thing from Wal-Mart I got for the kids.

Comment: The Pi is actually running great. No issues. I plugged in the HDMI first, then the controller... then the power source last. I even kept the tv's source on TV while I plugged it in. 

Once the Pi's green light stayed on, I switched the TV input over to HDMI 1 (the only HDMI port on this TV)

Comment: I see the boot log scroll by. Yesterday, it would do only that. Today, I actually got the Emulation Station start screen for about 6 seconds, then the tv turns BLUE and it says "No signal" as though I had nothing plugged in.

Comment: Again, I'm new to code and linux and the Pi... but I was able to do the above instruction great. I can do more, I just need someone to baby walk me through. HA! 

Anyway, what I am doing is building a system for a friend and I don't want him to go home and not be able to use any of his TVs. I built this using my 55" Samsung and the instructions above allowed me to run the Pi perfectly on it. Even now, I can set it up on that TV and it works great. But I'm fearing that my friend will have issues. Also, in the future, I want to replace a laptop with a newer Pi to use on this Element hdtv...

Comment: PART II: The other hdtv I was using is a 15" Insignia. It actually booted up and came on the screen. However, it's clunky. Red dots pixelate and pop up here or there. The controls are slower. The system freezes after a minute and goes to the blue "NO SIGNAL" screen.

I was hoping with the fix up above that it would allow the Pi to work on most any tv sets. But maybe I changed a setting in the Pi itself when it was hooked up to the 55" Samsung?? 

I was afraid to mess with the resolutions and stuff, as I don't know enough to do that yet.

Comment: So just now: On the ELEMENT tv. I turned it off and then back on again. Switched source back n forth. The Pi is on and waiting for me there. However, black lines jump around eratically. I can scroll. I just played an atari game. It was slightly skippy.

Comment: I fear the blue screen will pop up at any moment. I did open the file manager now... I see the config file... but I don't know what to do.

Comment: try changing the resolution. I assume you are using retropie/emulationStation. after the pi boots(successfully), press `f4` to get to the command line. then type `sudo raspi-config` to access the raspberry pi settings, go to `advanced options` using the arrow keys, select it using enter, then go down and select `resolution`, the select `default`, then select `finish` and `reboot now` with the tab key. see if this fixes the resolution problems.

Comment: Also, try doing a fresh install on your sd card, and this time, _don't_ change the config.txt file. try it out on the two tvs and let me know what happens. But turn the tv on _to hdmi_ _before_ plugging the pi in.

Comment: @SteveJ you can @mention people by putting an `@` symbol in front  of their name, that will make your message show up in their inbox at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It's amazing what I know today that I did not know just 7 days ago. This forum has been a great help. 

So, I changed the resolution, following your direction... and it popped right on the little 15" tv!! No stuttering, hesitating, red light blinking, black lines dancing around... NOTHING! It's been on for 2 hours now and all the games are running. 

I learned how to add the "super display" theme for ES and I've got all the titles and pics finally uploaded to the right places. Took more work to do the MAME games.

Comment: I was dreading doing a fresh install on the sd card, as I had done that twice before, believing something was wrong. But as long as I can move this Pi from tv to tv and it plays everywhere, I'm really happy.

Comment: Great @SteveJ !