# My Raspberry Pi won't boot no matter what I do (It has worked before, nothing is broken)

Tags: boot, kali

I followed the instructions from [this](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-build-a-portable-hacking-station-with-a-raspberr-1739297918) website on how to install Linux Kali on my Raspberry Pi Model B (which I have done before but had forgotten how to), and I plugged in the HDMI and microSD card, then after that I plugged in the power cable (it's the power cable for an Amazon Alexa, it delivers enough power) and waited for about 30 seconds just in case it was taking a while, but nothing happened.

I tried downloading the .img file again, still nothing. Rewriting it to the card, still nothing. Heck, I even tried plugging in a USB mouse before I plugged in the power just to see if that had any effect.

I'm almost entirely sure that there is nothing wrong with the Pi, it has worked before and has no physical damage to it; it was only a few weeks ago that I took out the microSD for extra storage in my phone (which I no longer needed the extra storage, hence using it in the Pi again).

You may be thinking, what if it is formatted wrongly then? It's not. I formatted it in FAT32 then I used Win32diskimager to write it to the microSD card. Maybe someone out there can help me with my particular problem?

Comment: have you tried a different distro? e.g. raspbian? Also, what does the activity light do when you switch the pi on?  flash in any particular pattern?

Comment: ["What do system LEDs signify?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/60563/78211)

Comment: Which "Kali" image did you download?

Answer (score 2):

First: I don't know how much power has the Amazon Alexa Charger, but anyway check if the charger has 5 Volts and MINIMALLY 2.0 Ampers,

Second: I can't acess the website, but confirm if the Raspberry Pi versions are the same (or compatible)

Third: Are you using a external screen? If you are using the mini touchscreen it normally doesn't show image, because your `HDMI mode` has to be configured to a specific number, to change the Pixels number, and others.

Fourth: Try to boot the Raspberry Pi with Raspbian OS, instaled by NOOBS. If it don't works with Raspbian OS, you have a problem with your Raspberry Pi, check if the `POWER` led turns ON and check if the `ACT` blinks at least 5 times.

Tell me something about this tips, and after thet i will give you some specific indications.

Comment: So I tested my pi, I have been using a distribution of Linux kali and that's why it wasn't working. There is a specific distribution of kali for the raspberry pi, but it won't boot. The Alexa charger definitely has enough output, I just tested it with raspbian and it works just fine. I just need a way to get kali to work on it Dx

Comment: @Aquatic So, the problem is of the Operative System or by the Way it was installed in your SD and RPi.
|
First: Check if the SD card has at least 16GB.
|
Second: Check if your Disk Imager is working well. For Windows i suggest YUMI and for Mac Etcher.
|
Third: Try to re-download the Image, it may be Corrupted.
|
Fourth: I Have no more ideas now, if i have, i will edit this comment :P, Good Night

Comment: I have checked all of these things, and everything works just fine. I tried checking the disk image for Linux kali for the pi, and apparently, there is a secondary file that downloads with it, but I cannot find it, I have redownloaded it multiple times to no avail. note- the pi could boot with raspbian

Comment: @Aquatic I will test and send you a good Kali disk image, juste tell me your Raspberry Pi version to me see if your version is compatible

Comment: [HERE](https://images.offensive-security.com/arm-images/kali-linux-2018.1a-rpi3-nexmon.img.xz) is a download link, but is compressed, first uncompress it then install it in your SD

Answer (score 2):

It's very common to write an image to the SD card that does not boot. If it does not boot the first time try writing another image.

I always start with the default raspbian because it is well maintained and will always boot. Once that works I typically use a 2nd SD for my experimental OS. Then if things stop working I can always verify my setup with a known good SD card.