# First time setup - no HDMI output

Tags: hdmi

At first install I get no output to my monitor at all. Have tried two different monitors and two different HDMI cables. Black screen. I assume this must be a hardware error, or have I missed something?
Connections:
- USB mouse
- USB keyboard
- USB card reader with preinstalled card (have tested that this reader works on another PC)
- Original Raspberry pi power supply connected and led lights stable red
- HDMI cable to monitor (two different tried and two different monitors)

Model: Pi3-b

Comment: The sd card goes in the built-in sd card slot on the Pi not in a card reader. Also, to rule out the obvious the HDMI cable and monitor need to be connected before booting.

Comment: Welcome! "I assume this must be a hardware error" not necessarily! What operating system have you installed? Is any status LED active (for details please read https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-do-system-leds-signify )? Please add these details to your question, not as comment.

Comment: I had a faulty SD card (that works perfectly well on a PC) that when inserted to a Pi caused nothing to happen when powered on. No signal out of the HDMI port. But in my situation, there were no lights on the Pi too.

Comment: Try the hdmi-safe option

Answer (score 0):

Does it output a black screen or does the monitor see no input? A stable red LED would mean that power is being supplied to the Raspberry Pi. Since you haven't mentioned a green LED flickering it would mean that it isn't doing anything.

Your microSD card has to go inside the built in microSD card slot on your Pi. You can't use the USB card reader.

Judging from your situation, you either have the microSD card plugged in the wrong place or you didn't format the card properly for the board.