# HDMI projector doesn't detect my PI

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 model B v1.1. I wanted to set It up for the first time. I loaded the  Raspbian Lite .img file into my 4Gb micro SDHC class 10. I put It in Its slot. I connected It to an EPSON HDMI Projector, a mouse and a keyboard. Then I connected the power cable (OUTPUT: 5V 2A) great!
The ACT led(green) is lightning but no blink(I think they say solid) the red does the same and the projector detects no signal (the cable works with my PC) I remove the card nothing changes, put it back again no change.
What exactly is happening? What I forgot?

Comment: Did you check if there is any signal on a different monitor or projector?

Comment: Are you sure the [ACT](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-do-system-leds-signify) LED (green) doesn't ever blink?

Comment: No blink, for the monitor I didn't try anything else but this one works well with my PC.

Comment: Also when I plug my mouse in I can't see the usual red laser color inside It,

Comment: Set (or uncomment) "hdmi_safe=1" in the file "/boot/config.txt"

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be caused by a lot os thing, check this and see if it results:

1. The Instalation:

   ·Have you INSTALLED the Raspbian OS Lite or just copied it to the SD?

2.

·Have you a monitor where you can test it? Just to verify the RPi's HDMI Output.

3.

·Try using PuTTY (Windows) or SSH Command (Linux) to connect remotely to your Raspberry Pi. Here you can see if th Pi works or not

Tell me if something helps pls

Comment: What is the difference between installing and copying Raspbian Lite? Normally we use `dd` to flash the image to the SD Card.

Comment: I mentioned above that I loaded .img file .for the last one can I setup ssh before even booting for the first time? If possible please tell me How?