# How can I turn the lights off on my pi?

Tags: hardware, led

I'd like to build a small internet radio out of my pi, but I'd like to use it at night, when the flashing LEDs would be disturbing. Is there any way to disable them?

Comment: Is a pair of pliers an inappropriate answer?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Fine, a way that *doesn't void the warranty*!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/697/797

Comment: This can be done via `sysfs` or `dtoverlay` in `/boot/config.txt` - [see this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112134/raspberry-pi-4-turn-red-led-off-via-software)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

Unfortunately not. The PWR LED, for example, is directly wired to the 5V rail and other LEDs are controlled by closed-binaries.

Comment: Sigh, electrical tape it is then.

Comment: Now possible - [see this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112134/raspberry-pi-4-turn-red-led-off-via-software)

Answer (score 13):

I know this may sound silly, but a piece of electricians tape over the top would work. Alternatively, put it in a case or box.

Comment: The best and most simple solution!

Answer (score 6):

There is answer in [How do I control the system LEDs using my software?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-do-i-control-the-system-leds-using-my-software)

For Power led, if you have RPI 2, then you can turn it off by using

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness # Power LED
```

It is taken from the last answer from post I referred.

Comment: Does not work RPI 3

Comment: @akhmed You can only turn off the activity (yellow) light in the PR3 using `echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` while logged in as root.