# Raspberry Pi 4: turn red LED off (via software)

Tags: power-supply

I have an RPI 4 in my room. When I sleep the red light fills a big part of the room. I don't want to turn the pi off as I want 24/7 availability. Its ability to be quiet and always available is why I find it appealing to use.

I thought about ducktaping it, but I find hardware solutions to be brutal (+ I can always do it if I get too fed up with it).

Is there a script I can write to turn it off?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Should work by writing the appropriate value to `/sys/class/leds/led1/trigger` on older OS.
Use `/sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/PWR/trigger` on kernel6 which replaced the confusing led1 with explicit PWR (ACT is used for activity LED).

`cat /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/PWR/trigger` will show all supported values; the value in `[…]` is the current value.

To permanently change use the `dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none` in `config.txt`

To switch it off use `none`, e.g.:

```
sudo su
echo none > /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger
#OR: 
echo none | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger
```

Use `default-on` to reverse it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for (and couldn't find via search engines, I'm still quite new to the Pi).

Comment: Clever! May I ask where you found the values (i.e. `none` and `default-on`) documented?

Comment: Even better: add `@reboot echo none > /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger` in root's crontab.

Comment: Works too on Raspberry Pi 4B

Answer (score 6):

There's a bunch of controls you can use in /boot/config.txt

```
    act_led_trigger         Choose which activity the LED tracks.
                            Use "heartbeat" for a nice load indicator.
                            (default "mmc")

    act_led_activelow       Set to "on" to invert the sense of the LED
                            (default "off")
                            N.B. For Pi 3B, 3B+, 3A+ and 4B, use the act-led
                            overlay.

    act_led_gpio            Set which GPIO to use for the activity LED
                            (in case you want to connect it to an external
                            device)
                            (default "16" on a non-Plus board, "47" on a
                            Plus or Pi 2)
                            N.B. For Pi 3B, 3B+, 3A+ and 4B, use the act-led
                            overlay.

    pwr_led_trigger
    pwr_led_activelow
    pwr_led_gpio
                            As for act_led_*, but using the PWR LED.
                            Not available on Model A/B boards.
```

And

```
Name:   act-led
Info:   Pi 3B, 3B+, 3A+ and 4B use a GPIO expander to drive the LEDs which can
    only be accessed from the VPU. There is a special driver for this with a
    separate DT node, which has the unfortunate consequence of breaking the
    act_led_gpio and act_led_activelow dtparams.
    This overlay changes the GPIO controller back to the standard one and
    restores the dtparams.
Load:   dtoverlay=act-led,<param>=<val>
Params: activelow               Set to "on" to invert the sense of the LED
                            (default "off")

    gpio                    Set which GPIO to use for the activity LED
                            (in case you want to connect it to an external
                            device)
                            REQUIRED
```

For example my Zero has

```
dtparam=act_led_activelow=on
```

so that the LED isn't a power LED, but works like a activity LED (on other RPis)

Take a look at `/boot/overlays/README` for details.

You probably want

```
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=on
```

to turn your RED LED off. I don't have a RPi4B, so I can't test that and confirm it does what you want. This does the same thing as @Dirk's answer but without needing a script run at boot time.

Comment: I've tried your answer, but it does not seem to work on my RPi 4B. I've tried from the command line (as you seem to suggest), and in `/boot/config.txt` using a `dtparam` line, and the `dtoverlay` as it suggests in `/boot/overlays/README`. It also seems that there is no `dtoverlay` for `pwr-led` as there is for `act-led`. It's fairly confusing in there - perhaps I've made a bodge of it?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to confirm and abbreviate Dougie's answer in that putting these lines in `/boot/config.txt` worked for me in accomplishing this goal:

```
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=on
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=on
```

Note that act_led_trigger/pwr_led_triger can be set to "none." There are various other options for these parameters, including "heartbeat." When you change this file, you will need to reboot the Pi in order to see the changes take effect; there might be a shortcut to avoid having to reboot that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Although it is derived from Dougie's answer, this is different enough to stand on it's own with a little editing.

Comment: The runtime shortcut is `echo gpio | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger`. Take a look at `/sys/class/leds` for proper names of your leds. Then you can blink them with `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` and `echo 0` consecutively.

Answer (score 2):

If you (like me) are using Ubuntu 20.04 server 64 bit, the file to edit is:

```
/boot/firmware/syscfg.txt
```

By adding the line:

```
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
```

In order to deactivate the LED permanently

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04 server-lts it is the:
`/boot/firmware/config.txt`

```
# Disable Power LED (Red)
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off

# Disable Activity LED (Green)
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=off

# Disable ethernet RJ45 cable LEDs
dtparam=eth_led0=4
dtparam=eth_led1=4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS 2023-02-21 (Bullseye ARM64), Seamus' answer works, however, after updating the operating system, these paths have now changed and one must use:

```
echo none | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/PWR/trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

My first post here but maybe this will help someone else.

I have had a bash alias commands to turn the light on my pi 4 on or off for a while.

Apparently, they changed the directory, and my bash alias commands of the past no longer worked on the latest version of pi buster / debain 11. It was not just a matter of changing the directory of where the bash alias command was pointed. I need an entirely new bash alias to turn the light on or off.

With the help of this post, I was able to make new bash alias commands to turn the light on my pi 4 on or off.

alias lightsoff='echo none | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/PWR/trigger'

alias lightson='echo default-on | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/PWR/trigger'

I hope this can help someone else trying to accomplish turning the lights on and off on their pi 4 with buster / debain 11

Answer (score -1):

[pi4 /boot/firmware/syscfg.txt]

## Disable the PWR LED

dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none

dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off

## Disable the Activity LED

dtparam=act_led_trigger=none

dtparam=act_led_activelow=off

## Disable ethernet port LEDs

dtparam=eth_led0=4

dtparam=eth_led1=4