# Why does sudo not work in this case?

Tags: debian, led, sudo

I was playing with the raspberry pi leds ([How do I control the system LEDs using my software?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-do-i-control-the-system-leds-using-my-software))

Interestingly, on my pi the following command fails:

```
sudo echo heartbeat >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

The error is **bash: /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger: Permission denied**

However if I run the following pair of commands things work:

```
sudo -s
echo heartbeat >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

I would have thought the two ways of triggering the LEDs are the same. Are there some things sudo cannot do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shell interprets and handles redirection **before** the command is executed.  So the redirection (>/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger) is attempted with the user's permissions, thus fails.

The generally recognized solution is to use the [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) command: ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)))

```
echo heartbeat | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger >/dev/null
```

The `tee` command splits (tees!) its input into two streams, one going to a file specified on the command line, the other to `stdout`.   In this example, I've used the ability to specify a filename to write to that file with sudo privileges, and discard the duplicate output going to stdout.

Comment: How do you disable this again?

Answer (score 6):

As explained by lornix it's because the shell handles redirection before the command is executed.

I prefer this type of invocation

```
sudo sh -c "echo 4 >/sys/class/gpio/export"
```

In your case

```
sudo echo heartbeat >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

would become

```
sudo sh -c "echo heartbeat >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
```

Comment: The answer above works on the pi zero: response = os.system("sudo sh -c \"echo {} >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness\"".format(led_to))